# show query meta_key_value including null value

Tags: mysql, wordpress, meta, nul

I am trying to do a simple query in WordPress ordered by a meta_value_num of a custom field, the problem is that not all the inputs have a value so it gives me a null value and it does not show very well in the query, it only shows the ones that have value, I have this code

```
  <ul class="post">
                <?php $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type'   => 'post',
                    'paged'       => $paged,
                    'meta_key'    => 'votes_count', 
                    'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num', 
                    'order'       => 'DESC',
                    'post_status' => 'publish'
                ); 
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                        get_template_part( 'public/partials/template/loop' );
                    endwhile; ?> 
                    <li class="numeration">
                        <div class="paginavi">
                             <?php YESPLEASE_Add_Theme_Support::yesplease_pagination(); ?>  
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endif;?>                  
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [meta_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/)
Try this below code.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'paged'       => $paged,
    'meta_key'    => 'votes_count', 
    'orderby'     => 'meta_value_num', 
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'votes_count',
            'value'   => array(''),
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It only shows the ones that have the value because *that is precisely what you're asking it to do.*

All I can think of to counter that is to make it a required field in the admin panel, or finding some other way of including it in the post object using, for example, ACF.

ACF is ***the*** most powerful plugin there is on the topic of adding custom fields that are easy to access in all post types, with extensive and easy-to-read documentation. By using ACF you can make it a required value in the post edit screen, or you can make it default to an actual value, like 0 instead of NULL.